# Why was my answer to my own question deleted?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I posted a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/368830/delete-multiple-files-on-powershell-command-line/368831#368831) about using the PowerShell rm command.  Then, I posted an answer, after making it clear I was also soliciting competing better answers.

My understanding is this fits with the letter and spirit of the FAQ, which says "It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question."  I have done this on StackOverflow without issue.

However, in this case my answer was deleted and moved to the question.

Answer (score 6):

If you check the edit summary for you question's [2nd revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/368830/2), and nhinkle's [comment](https://superuser.com/a/368831/39366) on your answer, it seems that people are confusing that answer for an edit to your question. They think you're providing an *update*, not an answer.

And I can see why - you've just dropped a command with no explanation of why or what it does. This is something that happens quite often around the site by people incorrectly 'answering' their own question with something that should be an update. The action in these cases is either straight-up deletion or conversion to an edit.

This means that when you *do* genuinely want answer your own question you should make it clear that you consider what you are posting in the answer to sufficiently and correctly solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think that would make sense as an edit.  It does answer the question correctly (it deletes the three files, which is what I said I wanted to do).  However, it's a valid point that I should have provided a brief explanation (which I will if someone gives me a heads up when it's undeleted).

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly clear that you meant to post it as an answer. Mistakes happen.

You mentioned in the question that your current approach was suboptimal, and then later posted it as an answer. So it's understandable that someone interpreted it as a failed attempt to edit your question; especially since you didn't explain anything about it and only posted the code snippet.

---

If you don't like @techie007's edit to your question, you can revert it (and maybe move the reference to your current approach to the answer), add some explanation to the answer, e.g. "This is what I'm currently using", and flag it for moderator attention to be undeleted. I'm not sure you can undelete it yourself, if you can, consider doing that.

---

For those of us that cannot view deleted posts: Matthew's answer is, in its entirety:

> ```
> echo subDir/a.png anotherDir/b.jpg thirdDir/c.gif|rm
> ```

Comment: I said in the original post "I will post what I'm currently using."  I didn't explicitly say I would post it as an answer (next time I will), but it shouldn't have been a surprise.  I did flag it for undeletion.  When it's undeleted I will be glad to add an explanation.

Comment: @matt you're right. Was easy to miss though. You should be able to edit the post even though it's deleted.

Comment: True, but working on an answer that only people with 10,000+ rep can see is not a good use of my time.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen .. and deleted posts can be undeleted. I'd urge you to revise the answer and when done flag it for undeletion